# Строку в массив байтов на golang

Tags: строки, golang, конвертация, байты

<sub>Перевод вопроса [How to assign string to bytes array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8032170).</sub>

Я хочу получить строку из массива байтов:

```
var arr [20]byte
str := "abc"
for k, v := range []byte(str) {
  arr[k] = byte(v)
}
```

Есть ли другой способ?

Comment: Вместо цикла автору исходного поста стоило воспользоваться функцией `copy`: `n:= copy(arr[:], []byte(str))`. Полный пример https://go.dev/play/p/0YTx0_jxiwd

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Перевод ответа [How to assign string to bytes array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28261008).</sub>

Просто и безопасно:

```
[]byte("Here is a string....")
```